# FindMinimum, NMinimize, etc. with external process

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization

I was hoping to be able to use MMA's minimization power to work with an external process. I want to minimize the function 'TryThisNumber[x_]' which sends the value of x to something external and gets back a result from that external object. I want to find the number which minimizes the returned result. But ... I can only talk to the external process using strings. So,  assume I have a function SendNumberToProcess[m_String] which does the actual communication with the process, I try:

```
TryThisNumber[x_]:= ToExpression[SendNumberToProcess[ToString[x]]];
```

and then,

```
FindMinimum[{TryThisNumber[a],0<a<10},{a}];
```

The problem is that ToString[x] in the above is just evaluating to the symbol, a, not a numerical value, and thus I'm not actually able to send a number to the external process. Any ideas?

Update. Presumably the problem is that FindMinimum has the HoldAll attribute, but this attempt doesn't work either:

```
TryThisNumber[x_]:= ToExpression[SendNumberToProcess[ToString[Evaluate[x]]]];
```

Comment: Have you tried `TryThisNumber[x_?NumericQ] := (* stuff *)`?

Comment: Thanks, tried that but makes no difference. It's presumably because FindMinimum etc have the attribute HoldAll. I thought maybe this would work, but it doesn't: TryThisNumber[x_]:= ToExpression[SendNumberToProcess[ToString[Evaluate[x]]]];

Comment: It seems you forgot the `NumericQ[]` in your new definition...

Comment: Dont forget when you define the function with the NumericQ pattern, the old generic argument definition is still there. Be sure to clear it..

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks!

Comment: @george2079 I think you could post that as an answer, since apparently solved the problem

Comment: Thanks @george2079 , I will. The only thing is, I also wanted to ask what exactly is going on with the ?NumericQ construct, or rather, why specifically does it solve this problem. I'm not sure I understand the reason ( I'm an MMA newbie )

Comment: "I also wanted to ask what exactly is going on with the ?NumericQ construct, or rather, why specifically does it solve this problem." - See [this](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820). In short, the routines will first attempt a symbolic analysis of your objective function. If the function you want to optimize cannot be subjected to such analysis, then you need the `_?NumericQ` in the definition.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to J.M. and george2079, this works:

```
TryThisNumber[x_?NumericQ] := ToExpression[SendNumberToProcess[ToString[x]]];
```