# _?NumericQ equivalent for lists

Tags: expression-test

A few months ago I got a simple answer (see: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10918/findminimum-nminimize-etc-with-external-process) ) to the question of how to force numeric evaluation during use of functions such as `NMinimize[]` - namely the use of `_?NumericQ` in the argument list.

I now have the same problem, only this time the argument to the user-defined function I'm trying to minimize is a list. Is there an equivalent to `_?NumericQ` for lists?

Comment: Try `(VectorQ[#,NumericQ]&)`

Comment: Do you mean like this? MyFunction[arg_?(VectorQ[#,NumericQ]&)]

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: You can look here too http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7120/pattern-test-for-variables-during-function-definition

Comment: How about just: `p : {_?NumericQ ..}`

Comment: ... or just `p:{__?NumericQ}`?

Answer (score 35):

You have several options:

```
foo[arg_?(VectorQ[#,NumericQ]&)] 

foo[arg: {_?NumericQ ..}]

foo[arg: {__?NumericQ}]
```

For matrices or higher dimensional arrays, the equivalent of `VectorQ` is `MatrixQ` and `ArrayQ`.

It's worth noting that `VectorQ[..., NumericQ]` (and its relatives `MatrixQ` and `ArrayQ`) are highly optimized and will avoid unpacking packed arrays:

```
match = RandomReal[1, 10^6];
unpacked = Append[match, 1];
nonmatch = Append[match, "x"];

Table[
 Timing[MatchQ[set, _?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)]], {set, {match, 
   unpacked, nonmatch}}]

(* {{0.000016, True}, {0.003106, True}, {0.003184, False}} *)

Table[
 Timing[MatchQ[set, _?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ[#] &] &)]], {set, {match, 
   unpacked, nonmatch}}]

(* {{0.402001, True}, {0.364469, True}, {0.362019, False}} *)

Table[
 Timing[MatchQ[set, {_?NumericQ ..}]], {set, {match, unpacked, 
   nonmatch}}]

(* {{0.266730, True}, {0.231373, True}, {0.229849, False}} *)

Table[
 Timing[MatchQ[set, {__?NumericQ}]], {set, {match, unpacked, 
   nonmatch}}]

(* {{0.226045, True}, {0.158696, True}, {0.160493, False}} *)
```