# Sequence and boolean And

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

I'm trying to figure out if a calculation result it's a valid result. As it return a matrix, I need to test that every element it's a number, so I thought this could work...

```
numericTable = Range[12] ~Partition ~ 4;
check=( NumberQ/@Flatten@numericTable) /.List->Sequence ;
And[check]
```

This should return `True` or `False` depending if exist or not a non-numerical element in the matrix. But it returns

```
Sequence[True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True]
```

So I don't understand anything, because...

```
In[]:= Sequence[True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True]===check
And[Sequence[True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True]]
Out[]= True
Out[]= True
```

Where's the catch ???

Comment: Why not just `And @@ (NumberQ /@ Flatten@numericTable)`?

Comment: Or a combination of `MatrixQ` and `NumberQ` as in the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixQ.html) ?

Comment: @PinguinDirk you're right... in fact I found some code where I did that, but still I would like to understand where's the problem with Sequence...

Comment: @SMiranda: I suspect it is cause of `HoldAll` attribute of `And` - thus, `And[evaluate@check]` works. But I have to admit I am not sure...

Comment: @PinguinDirk Yep, That's it. I was going to post that as an answer, now you could do it yourself

Comment: @PinguinDirk Compare `Plot[Evaluate[Sequence[Sin]][x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]` with `Plot[Sequence[Sin][x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]` ... Plot has also `HoldAll`

Comment: @belisarius - thanks for the example - I will post an answer - feel free to edit that later. thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16694/5

Comment: `MatrixQ[numericTable, NumberQ]` seems reasonable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As in the comments above, we see that the `HoldAll` attribute is causing the "problem".

Note that if we unset `HoldAll` it works:

```
Unprotect@And;
ClearAttributes[And, HoldAll];
Protect@And;
```

Then:

```
And[check]
```

> True

EDIT: based on Oleksandr R.'s comment, I must stress that I showed this only to illustrate the "problem". It is not a good idea to unset `HoldAll` for `And`, as noted below in his comment. So as in my comment to the question above, you can just use `Evaluate` to get the result:

```
And[Evaluate@check]
```

to get to the same result.

(END EDIT)

You could directly apply `And` on what you constructed:

```
And @@ (NumberQ /@ Flatten@numericTable)
```

but better check MrWizard's answer for a direct solution of your problem.

Comment: Well done! :) ..

Comment: & thanks for your input!

Comment: Removing `HoldAll` is a very bad idea in the case of `And`: it destroys the short-cut evaluation semantics, which are frequently relied upon for correctness. If you know you don't need this in a particular situation, a better way is to apply `Evaluate` *for that case only* or inject the evaluated argument using `With`. I'm downvoting for now due to this, but will remove it when you update your answer to override `HoldAll` more "correctly".

Comment: @OleksandrR.: it was meant to illustrate the point, but thanks for pointing it out that it is misleading - I will edit my post accordingly. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Earned the +1 after your edit

Answer (score 8):

In addition to `HoldAll` as highlighted by [Pinguin Dirk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5274/pinguin-dirk) the other component of the behavior is that `And` directly returns single arguments:

```
And[73]
```

> ```
> 73
> ```

Combined, `And[check]` spits out `check` which at the top level evaluates to `Sequence[True, . . .]`.

One problem with your method for checking the matrix is that it does not short-circuit on a non-numeric value, and therefore it may waste time.  That is, `NumberQ` is applied to every element even if the very first one is non-numeric.  A faster approach is to use the built-in `MatrixQ`:

```
MatrixQ[numericTable, NumberQ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: I accept the @PinguinDirk response because I only accept just one and he was first, but thank you for your response (and other responses all over the MSE, I'm a fan ;-)