# What is the correct way to use NIntegrate inside the FindMinimum function?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, mathematical-optimization

I'm having minor issues with the `FindMinimum` function when using `NIntegrate` inside. The functions work perfectly well but I get warning messages and I was wondering if maybe I could be enlightened on the correct usage of these two functions together.

For the sake of illustration I provide the full set of functions I used on a simple example.

```
phi[t_, k_, h_] := (1/h)^3*
   Piecewise[{{(h (1 - k) + t)^2 (h (1 + 2 k) - 2 t), (k - 1) h <= t <= 
       k*h}, {(h (1 + k) - t)^2 (h (1 - 2 k) + 2 t), 
      k*h <= t <= (k + 1) h}}];
psi[t_, k_, h_] := (1/h)^3*
   Piecewise[{{(t - k*h) (h + t - k*h)^2, (k - 1) h <= t <= 
       k*h}, {(t - k*h) (h - t + k*h)^2, k *h <= t <= (k + 1)*h}}] ;
phipp[t_, k_, h_] := (1/h)^3*
   Piecewise[{{2 (h (1 + 2 k) - 2 t) - 8 (h (1 - k) + t), (k - 1) h <= 
       t <= k*h}, {-8 (h (1 + k) - t) + 2 (h (1 - 2 k) + 2 t), 
      k*h <= t <= (k + 1) h}}];
psipp[t_, k_, h_] := (1/h)^3*
   Piecewise[{{2 (-h k + t) + 4 (h - h k + t), (k - 1) h <= t <= 
       k*h}, {-4 (h + h k - t) + 2 (-h k + t), 
      k*h <= t <= (k + 1) h}}];
alpha[t_, k_, h_] := phi[t, k, h] + phipp[t, k, h];
beta[t_, k_, h_] := psi[t, k, h] + psipp[t, k, h];
T = Pi;
n = 2;
h = T/n;
FindMinimum[
 NIntegrate[(h*beta[t, 0, h] - h*beta[t, n, h] + 
     a.Table[alpha[t, i, h], {i, 1, n - 1}] + 
     b.Table[h*beta[t, i, h], {i, 1, n - 1}])^2, {t, 0, 
   T}], {{a, {0.76}}, {b, {0.4}}}, Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]
```

I get the following warning message :

```
NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand (a.{(8 Piecewise[{<<2>>},0])/\[Pi]^3+(8 Piecewise[{<<2>>},0])/\[Pi]^3}+b.{1/2\\[Pi]\(8\Power[<<2>>]\Piecewise[<<2>>]+8\Power[<<2>>]\Piecewise[<<2>>])}-1/2\\[Pi]\((8 Piecewise[{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}},0])/\[Pi]^3+(8 Piecewise[{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}},0])/\[Pi]^3)+1/2\\[Pi]\((8 Piecewise[{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}},0])/\[Pi]^3+(8 Piecewise[{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}},0])/\[Pi]^3))^2 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,3.14159}}"
```

I ask about this because `FindMinimum` takes unexpectedly long time to converge to the solution (which is a right one). But I thought that maybe using the functions correctly will accelerate the process.

Comment: Try defining your functions as `phi[t__?NumericQ,..]` and so on for all arguments.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Tried it, I'm still getting the warnings...

Comment: maybe `a.Table[alpha[t, i, h], {i, 1, n - 1}]` isn't the best way to go here.

Comment: Is this a smaller version of a bigger problem ? If not, you can do the integration symbolically, it's a very simple function.

Comment: @b.gatessucks It is indeed a smaller version of a bigger problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is indeed that Mathematica tries to do numerical operations before the symbols have value. You can fix this as follows.

**Preliminary definitions, unchanged from yours**

```
phi[t_, k_, h_] := (1/h)^3*
   Piecewise[{{(h (1 - k) + t)^2 (h (1 + 2 k) - 2 t), (k - 1) h <= 
       t <= k*h}, {(h (1 + k) - t)^2 (h (1 - 2 k) + 2 t), 
      k*h <= t <= (k + 1) h}}];
psi[t_, k_, h_] := (1/h)^3*
   Piecewise[{{(t - k*h) (h + t - k*h)^2, (k - 1) h <= t <= 
       k*h}, {(t - k*h) (h - t + k*h)^2, k*h <= t <= (k + 1)*h}}];
phipp[t_, k_, h_] := (1/h)^3*
   Piecewise[{{2 (h (1 + 2 k) - 2 t) - 8 (h (1 - k) + t), (k - 1) h <=
        t <= k*h}, {-8 (h (1 + k) - t) + 2 (h (1 - 2 k) + 2 t), 
      k*h <= t <= (k + 1) h}}];
psipp[t_, k_, h_] := (1/h)^3*
   Piecewise[{{2 (-h k + t) + 4 (h - h k + t), (k - 1) h <= t <= 
       k*h}, {-4 (h + h k - t) + 2 (-h k + t), 
      k*h <= t <= (k + 1) h}}];
alpha[t_, k_, h_] := phi[t, k, h] + phipp[t, k, h];
beta[t_, k_, h_] := psi[t, k, h] + psipp[t, k, h];
T = Pi;
n = 2;
h = T/n;
```

**Pull the integral out of the `FindMinimum` and make it only evaluate for numerical lists**

Here's the integral, defined so as to only evaluate for [numeric lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16694/16). This is cumbersome because of the way `a` is defined (to be a list).

```
ClearAll[fn];
fn[a_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), b_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := 
 NIntegrate[(h*beta[t, 0, h] - h*beta[t, n, h] + 
     a.Table[alpha[t, i, h], {i, 1, n - 1}] + 
     b.Table[h*beta[t, i, h], {i, 1, n - 1}])^2, {t, 0, T}]
```

And now `FindMinimum` has no problem:

```
FindMinimum[fn[a, b], {{a, {0.76}}, {b, {0.4}}}, 
 Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]