# How to properly apply NumericQ or s.th. similar here? - NDSolve inside NMaximize

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, expression-test

I wrote a function that numerically solves a given Schrodinger equation and returns replacement rules to obtain the time evolution operator. It looks and is used as follows:

```
solver[H_, time_] := 
    soln = Module[{d, init, eqs, vars, solargs, t, t0, tf},
    d = Dimensions[H][[1]];
    t0 = time[[2]];
    tf = time[[3]];
    t = time[[1]];
    u[t_] := Table[Subscript[u, i, j][t], {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}];
    init = Thread[Flatten /@ (u[t0] == IdentityMatrix[d])];
    eqs = Thread[Flatten /@ (I*u'[t] == H.u[t])];
    vars = Flatten[Table[Subscript[u, i, j], {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}]];
    solargs = Join[eqs, init];
    Return[NDSolve[solargs, vars, time, InterpolationOrder -> All, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", AccuracyGoal -> 10]]
  ];

(* use like this, e.g. for 2D problem*)
ham[t_]:={{0,t},{t,0}};
solEvol=solver[ham[t],{t,0,20}];
evolOp[t_]=u[t]/.solEvol[[1]];
```

I do now need to work with the result obtained from my `solver` inside e.g. `NMaximize` to determine several parameters. To simplify things I reduced my original code/question to this snippet:

```
testFun[mat_] := Abs[mat];
uTemp2D[t_] := Table[Subscript[u, i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
hamParam[t_] = {{a, t}, {t, a}};
optimum = NMaximize[
    {testFun[uTemp2D[20] /. solver[hamParam[t], {t, 0, 20}]], 
    -10 < a < 10}, 
    a, 
    Method -> {"NelderMead"}
  ];
```

As far as I understand this now evaluates to

```
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
ReplaceAll::reps: (* here come all entries of eqs in solver function*) is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."
```

because `NDSolve` in `solver` does get non-numerical values (here `a`) as input. So the order of evaluation is incorrect. I thought of using something like `_?NumericQ` for matrices (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19600) but that is either working nor necessary accoring to a comment by MichaelE2.

## Question

So in brief, what is the proper way to define my `solver` function or maybe the `testFun` to get results for my variable `optimum`?

---

## Original code snippets (to which MichaelE2's answer refers)

Originally I was intending to execute the following (`hParam[t]` same as above):

```
partialTrace[states_, mat_] :=
  Module[{l = Length[states], trace},
   trace = Sum[{states[[i]]}\[Conjugate].mat.states[[i]], {i, 1, l}];
   Return[trace];
 ];

fidelPhase[evol_, Uideal_, states_] := 
  Module[{result}, 
   result = (1/(Length[states])^2)*(Abs[
   partialTrace[states, Uideal\[ConjugateTranspose].evol]])^2; 
   Return[result];];

solver[H_, time_, index_] := 
  soln = Module[{d, init, eqs, vars, solargs, t, t0, tf,meth = index}, 
  d = Dimensions[H][[1]];
  t0 = time[[2]];
  tf = time[[3]];
  t = time[[1]];
  u[t_] := Table[Subscript[u, i, j][t], {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}];
  init = Thread[Flatten /@ (u[t0] == IdentityMatrix[d])];
  eqs = Thread[Flatten /@ (I*u'[t] == H.u[t])];
  vars = Flatten[Table[Subscript[u, i, j], {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}]];
  solargs = Join[eqs, init];
  Return[
    Which[
      meth == 1, NDSolve[solargs, vars, time, InterpolationOrder -> All, AccuracyGoal -> 10],
      meth == 2, NDSolve[solargs, vars, time, InterpolationOrder -> All, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 15}}, StartingStepSize -> 1/300, AccuracyGoal -> 10],
      meth == 3, NDSolve[solargs, vars, time, InterpolationOrder -> All, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", AccuracyGoal -> 10]
     ]
   ];
 ];

optimizer[gateTime_, ham_, ideal_, vars_, range_, states_] :=
  Module[{params},
  params = Map[Flatten, Transpose[{vars, range}]];
  solsOpt = NMaximize[
    fidelPhase[uTemp3D[gateTime]/.solver[ham/.tg -> gateTime, {t,0,gateTime},3][[1]], ideal,states],
  params,
  Method -> {"NelderMead", "Tolerance" -> Sqrt[$MachineEpsilon]}
  ];
  Return[solsOpt];
 ];

uIdeal = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
test = optimizer[
    20, hParam[t], uIdeal, 
    {a, b}, {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}
  ];
```

which now works with MichaelE2's answer.

Comment: `solver[H_?(MatrixQ[#,NumericQ]&), time_, index_] :=..` requires your Hamiltonian consist of explicit numbers (no variables such as `t`, such as `h[t]` has). This should be fine, `solver[H_, time_, index_] :=..`, as you have in the beginning.  At least it yields solutions.  Since `uTemp3D` is not a variable of your system and not defined elsewhere, I don't know what to do with it or the rest of your problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Indeed I forgot to add the `uTemp3D` defintion. I updated my question and added a concrete example of what is not working together with the error message(s) given. Hopefully the problem is a bit more clarified now.

Comment: To get more and better answers, try to simplify your real problem to a minimal example.

Comment: @belisarius I updated my question and reduced it to a minimal example for my problem. Hopefully it is now easier to read and understand.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I updated my question and reduced it to a minimal example for my problem. Hopefully it is now easier to read and understand.

Comment: @Lukas I had kinda halfway figured it out before your latest edit.  My job keeps me from finishing and writing up the answer nicely.  Anyway I just figured out the last problem and posted my fixes to the code as it was.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks alot for your solution! I added the original snippets that fit to your answer so that everything can be understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primary fixes: Adding `First` to `fidelPhase` and adding `t` to `Subscript[u, i, j][t]`.  Making an objective function `obj` that is not evaluated until `a` and `b` are numeric may or may not be important. I won't have time to check it out (I've lost track of the original `optimizer`).  The following works and it's not crucial to be so precise in one's fixes.

```
Clear[optimizer];
optimizer[gateTime_, ham_, ideal_, vars_, range_, states_] := 
 Module[{params, obj},
  obj[v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ]] := 
   First@fidelPhase[
     uTemp3D[gateTime] /. 
      solver[ham /. Thread[vars -> v] /. tg -> gateTime, {t, 0, 
         gateTime}, 3][[1]], ideal, states];
  params = Map[Flatten, Transpose[{vars, range}]];
  solsOpt = 
   NMaximize[obj[vars], params, 
    Method -> {"NelderMead", "Tolerance" -> Sqrt[$MachineEpsilon]}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Print];
  Return[solsOpt];]

uTemp3D[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i, j][t], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
```

Comment: This works brilliant. Thanks alot! One further question: is this the approach one would usually choose for dealing with problems of that kind or is it just like the best fit to my specific problem?

Comment: @Lukas I would say that coding the objective function as a separate `obj` with `NumericQ` protection of the `NMaximize` variables is a general technique, in the case where the function is defined in terms of numeric functions such as `NDSolve`, `NIntegrate`, `FindRoot`,.... (When the function is an algebraic formula, it's usually better **not** to have `NumericQ` to allow symbolic analysis.)  Whether there's a better overall approach to your particular problem is not something I had time to think about....

Comment: ...I suspect the two minor "fixes" were hard to detect and confusing. One might try to think if there's a simpler way to build the solution, so that such errors are discovered earlier or more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the brief explanation. I do highly appreciate any help and information to become better in using Mathematica.