# Can I make NumericQ Listable? Why isn't there an Option to test in ListQ?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test

I have a function which takes lists as arguments. **But it shall be evaluated only, if the elements in the lists are all numeric.** Otherwise I want the function to remain unevaluated.

There is a function NumericQ, but if I apply it to a list, e.g.

`NumericQ[{1, 2.1, Pi}]` gives  `False`

and

`NumericQ /@ {1, 2.1, Pi}` gives `{True, True, True}`

In the documentation it shows a nice example applying a NumericQ-Test to all *Matrix* elements `MatrixQ[m, NumericQ]` where m is a matrix with NumericQ True for all its elements.

This gave me the idea to do the same with ListQ (unfortunately it is not in the documentation, although ?ListQ gives some information on it).

But unlike MatrixQ, ListQ does not have an optional parameter test, so ListQ[list, NumericQ] is not available.

**Would it be possible to add such a capability to ListQ and how would one do that?**

I looked up `Attributes[ListQ]` which yields `{Protected}` and `Attributes[NumberQ]` which also yields `{Protected}`, booth don't have Listable among their attributes.

**Would there be adverse effects if one would add Listable to one of them?**

Of course, the solution to my original problem, *test if a list has all numerical entries*, is solved by this function:

```
Apply[And, Map[NumericQ, #]] &
```

But my more genral questions are not answered by it.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/numericq-equivalent-for-lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to make `NumericQ` listable.  `{1,2,3}` is most definitely *not* numeric, even though `1`, `2` and `3` individually are.

But you can always define your own function which does what you need.

The best way to do this is

```
VectorQ[#, NumericQ]&
```

Why is this the *best* way out of many possible ways?  Because `VectorQ` is optimized for this special case and will return `True` for packed arrays immediately, without unpacking them or testing each element with `NumericQ` individually.  It's an $O(1)$ operation.

---

About `ListQ`: I guess you were just looking for `VectorQ`.

> Would there be adverse effects if one would add Listable to one of them?

Most definitely yes.  Never modify fundamental builtins such as `ListQ` or `NumericQ`, as they are used in many places internally.  Doing this *will* break stuff and it will do it when you least expect it.

Comment: Thancs, Szabolcs! I alos had doubts to modify such a fundamental symbol als ListQ, that's why I asked. VectorQ is the perfect one-dimensional equivalent to MatrixQ: It also has an optional test function.

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen You may also be interested in `ArrayQ`, which is a generalization of `VectorQ` and `MatrixQ`.  There are some important differences between `VectorQ` and `ListQ`: `ListQ` always gives `False` on a `SparseArray` because it really only checks that the `Head` is `List`.  `VectorQ[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]` gives `False` because the argument is a matrix, not a vector.  However, using a second argument allows it to return `True`: `VectorQ[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, True&]`.

Comment: I did not know that one. In this case the documentation has some beautiful examples, also one how to overcome the "pattern" if not needed. They show ArrayQ[{{{E, 1}, {Pi, 2}}, {{Sin[1], Cos[2]}, {Sinh[1], 
    Cosh[1]}}}, _, NumericQ] - I'll keep that in mind, it might be useful.