# How to search effectively for information on MMA Syntax such as "_?"

Tags: syntax, documentation

In another question here, I saw this

`poincareMetric[u_?VectorQ, v_?VectorQ] :=` ...

Whilst I am familiar with the syntax label_Type, e.g. x_Real, I had not seen this form, but when I tried to search the MMA documentation I found that searching for `_?` returned no results and neither `_` or `?` on their own suggested to me a clear meaning for `_?` - especially since I would have written `u_List` for `u_?VectorQ`

So,

1/ What does `_?` actually mean, and

2/ What is this function definition doing that would not be done by e.g. `u_List`?

but most importantly,

3/ How does one search for help on such terse syntactic constructions effectively? (So as not to ask almost trivial questions here)

Comment: Almost all of these can be found by a documentation search.  Your only mistake is assuming that `_?` is a single unit.  It's `_` and `?` separately.  You can search for both.

Comment: Otherwise look at this post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616

Comment: [Also see my comments on VectorQ here.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129815/can-i-make-numericq-listable-why-isnt-there-an-option-to-test-in-listq/129819?noredirect=1#comment350688_129819)

Comment: Whilst searching for "\_" produced only 1 result, searching for "?" produced 1055 hits. Searching for "_ ?" returned none. When you say I could "search for both", what could I enter in the search box (one search) or how could I combined multiple searches? (process) to identify relevant entries? Also, following links I arrive at controlling order of evaluation "define the function f to only evaluate if it receives a numeric value by using NumericQ and pattern testing. Append the pattern ?NumericQ to the argument of the function f"... TBC

Comment: I also tried `a[x_?VectorQ] := Module[{}, Print["Executed"]; True];
b[x_List] := Module[{}, Print["Executed"]; True]` and didn't find any difference with various inputs. Under what conditions might they be different?

Comment: Searching for `?` produces precisely three results.  It has two uses in Mathematica syntax and one in regular expressions. Go to Help -> Wolfram Documentation, type `?` and hit Enter.  Use the builtin documentation, not Google or the Wolfram website.

Comment: "Under what conditions might they be different" <- Please do read the comment I linked to above, where I gave two examples. The VectorQ documentation explains more.

Comment: I am searching the Documentation Center as a whole (and in fact get 10547 hits). I must be searching in the wrong place. Ah, no... you meant search for "?" WITH QUOTES; I was searching for "?" without quotes. I think that's quite an important difference ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47629/discussion-between-julian-moore-and-szabolcs).

Comment: For completeness here: as @Szabolcs said, one can search... however different versions of MMA work differently: in V9(.0.1, tested on Windows 7 64-bit) to find the limited number of results expected by a user of a later version, one must put the question mark in double quotes thus `"?"` if one is to find a sensible number of results: using only `?` in that version of MMA returned over 10,000 results.