# NIntegrate fails because of symbolic evaluation

Tags: numerical-integration, argument-patterns

The following function can be plotted without any issues, say with `ContourPlot`, but `NIntegrate` fails because it tries to diagonalise the matrix with generic values `x,y`, instead of using numerical values.

```
del1 = {1, 0}; del2 = {1, Sqrt[3]}/2; del3 = del2 - del1;

matrix[k_] := {{1, Cos[k.del3/2],Cos[k.del1/2]},
  {Cos[k.del3/2],1,Cos[k.del2/2]}, {Cos[k.del1/2], Cos[k.del2/2], 1}};

fun[k_] := Block[{d = 0, abc, esys, UU},
  esys = Eigensystem[N[matrix[k]]];
  UU = Transpose[Normalize /@ esys[[2]]];
  abc = ConjugateTranspose[UU].DiagonalMatrix[{.1, 5, 0}].UU;
  abc[[1, 1]]]

NIntegrate[fun[{x, y}], {x, .3, .4}, {y, .3, .4}]
```

I have tried putting `Evaluate` and `?NumericQ` in a few places, to no avail. 
How can I perform the desired integral?

Comment: Try `ClearAll[fun];` before defining `fun` to erase all previous defs. Then `fun[k_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := ...` seems to work for me.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this does indeed work. I would have never guessed that... Any reason why `NIntegrate` needs this but `ContourPlot` doesn't?

Comment: I can't really explain it. Generally you've got `solver[f[x], domain]`, where solver might be `NIntegrate`, `ContourPlot`, etc. The `solver` holds the code `f` (it does not evaluate immediately). Now, sometimes you want the solver to evaluate `f` and analyze the result (e.g., for method selection, to handle singularities); sometimes not. The other choice is whether the solver uses the evaluated code `f` or uses the original code for numeric evaluation. I think this choice is the difference, but I can't explain why `ContourPlot` chooses a different way from `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16694,
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
del1 = {1, 0}; del2 = {1, Sqrt[3]}/2; del3 = del2 - del1;

matrix[k : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] := 
 {{1, Cos[k.del3/2], Cos[k.del1/2]}, 
  {Cos[k.del3/2], 1, Cos[k.del2/2]}, 
  {Cos[k.del1/2], Cos[k.del2/2], 1}}

fun[k : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] :=
  Module[{d = 0, abc, esys, UU},
    esys = Eigensystem[N[matrix[k]]];
    UU = Transpose[Normalize /@ esys[[2]]];
    abc = ConjugateTranspose[UU].DiagonalMatrix[{.1, 5, 0}].UU;
    abc[[1, 1]]]

NIntegrate[fun[{x, y}], {x, .3, .4}, {y, .3, .4}]
```

> `0.0170039`

Note: The argument pattern given in the definitions of `matrix` and `fun` is the critical change. The change of `Block` to `Module` is not critical; I just think it is better practice in this case.